# How to create correlation using dplyr in R studio

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data set with 3 attributes (organization hierarchy region-area-territory, territory is the lowest grain) plus two numeric fields (sales qty and headcount).

How do I generate correlation between sales qty and territory headcount, and display the correlation by region, area and territory?

I used dplyr package, g=group_by (mydataset, region, area, territory), and then summarize(g, cor(sales_qty, headcount).  The display looks right, but all correlation is 'NA'.  If I omit territory, then the result looks right (group by region and area).  Even though territory is the lowest level, can I still use 'group_by' feature? Why is it showing NA?

Thank you for helping!

Comment: What is `count(g)`? Is the count column a column of 1's?

Answer (score 0):

Without looking at your code it is hard to tell what you are trying. I can't comment what you are doing wrong. Here is what I have tried to get correlation with groups. It works well.

```
set.seed(1234)
df <- data.frame(group = rep(1:5, 100), x = rnorm(500) , y = rnorm(500) )
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  do(data.frame(x=cor(.$x,.$y)))
```

**Output:**

```
 group             x
  <int>         <dbl>
1     1  0.1293551648
2     2  0.0006703073
3     3  0.2021294935
4     4 -0.0162522307
5     5  0.0995898089
```